# How to use Secure WebSocket with java client and custom python server?

Tags: java, python, autobahn

So what i would like is a secure connection between my phone (java) and my raspberry pi.

I already made a custom server with the help of autobahn wich is on my github (i can't post more link...).
And i don't understand why the client doesn't need any keys or anything to connect to the server.
I followed the readme [here](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/twisted/websocket/echo_tls) in order to create my key there (i know that i should not share them, but i will recreate my own keys when the project will be finished).

And i've found that for the [Java-websocket](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/blob/master/src/main/example/SSLClientExample.java) module it needs some keystore to run. And i think that having a storepass and keypass like this in a .java is not secure at all, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

what java need is the certificate to confirm the validity of the autosigned key.

the python client trust automatically all certificate.

Here is the server : https://github.com/flyingrub/SSWOD

And here the server : https://github.com/flyingrub/SecureKey